# installation of xCode 4.2 with iOS5 SDK beta 5 failed

Tags: ios, xcode

I had downloaded the latest beta version (5) of SDK and tried to install on my MacBookPro, but strangely enough it failed to be installed. Very strange looks  the required space 0 for installation, even I have checked all items to be installed.
I am currently using OSX 10.6.8, but no idea what could be a problem regarding this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should update to Lion.

Comment: I am using Snow Leopard and don't wanna change it.

Comment: So, than Xcode 4.2 is not for you.

Comment: Basically I use an installation package for Snow Leopard OSX, downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#. So I guess it would be something else. But thanx anyhow for recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You should install Lion os 10.7 for using ios5. refer this link [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4427/wwdc-2011-ios-5)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my MacBook Pro but I installed it successfully on my iMac, both running snow leopard. I guess it must be something related to the hardware where it is attempted to be installed. The same happens with Lion. Lion allegedly requires at least Intel Core 2 Duo. My MacBook Pro is an older one with a Intel Core Duo processor, so Lion won't run on it. My guess is that XCode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 beta 5 requires the same. XC 4.2 w iOS 5.0 b 4 runs well though.